# Node.js Express Websocket clients coming from http origin?

Tags: node.js, express, websocket

I have a webapp that communicates to Node.js Express server using websocket.

When verifying the websocket connection, I check the ORIGIN header of the request (and a few other parameters to ensure they are legitimate)

The expected request is either "https://www.mywebsite.com" or "https://mywebsite.com"

If the ORIGIN header is not expected, we will kick the user.

Then I noticed some people can be kicked when their socket connection looks alright, but the ORIGIN is "http://mywebsite.com". We quickly checked and realise the website can be visited in http. We added a piece of redirect code like this:

```
const server = express() 
  .enable('trust proxy')
  .use((req, res, next) => {
      req.secure ? next() : res.redirect('https://' + req.headers.host + req.url)
  })
```

And now theoretically, whoever visit the http version of the website should be redirected to https.

But, even this redirection is done, we still notice people being kicked because their origin is http instead of https. Why is this so? Is there any chance that some users can never use https?

Comment: Is the traffic served directly by Node.js? Don't you use a reverse proxy like nginx?

Comment: @Andrei no nginx, hosted on Heroku

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct way to redirect to https on Heroku:

> Under the hood, Heroku router (over)writes the X-Forwarded-Proto and the X-Forwarded-Port request headers. The app must check X-Forwarded-Proto and respond with a redirect response when it is not https but http.

Taken from: https://help.heroku.com/J2R1S4T8/can-heroku-force-an-application-to-use-ssl-tls

This is some sample code you can use:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (req.header('x-forwarded-proto') !== 'https') {
    res.redirect(`https://${req.header('host')}${req.url}`)
  } else {
    next()
  }
})
```

<strike>The reason your code doesn't work is that Heroku does SSL termination for you and serves the certificates this means the connection between the Heroku router and your Node.js server is insecure and `req.secure` returns false:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing#routing</strike>
Correction: Cause you set trust proxy this means req.protocol will be set to https and req.secure will return true so your code will work.

Comment: But the strange thing is, my code works for me - if type http:// on my browser, I can see it redirecting to https version correctly, so I don't understand why some people can reach my website without being redirected to https. Anyway I will try ur code too!

Comment: @mkto You might be correct cause you set `trust proxy` this means req.protocol will be set to https and req.secure will return true so your code will work.

Comment: @mkto We need more details, what does a `curl -I http://mywebsite.com` request return? Does it have 302 status code and a Location header?

Comment: yes now since I have updated to your code, I see 302 and Location header saying https:// mywebsite.com - hopefully all is good?